# Creating directories from filename?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, directory, storage

I'm creating website that handles "great amount" of images. I have decided to use multiple directories method for storing files eg. `images/efg/ed/ehj/efgedehjokjvdf2jn4.jpg`

I'm thinking that to prevent filename duplication is to take current timedate + some random string + md5 those = nice line of random string. Mostly I'm wondering method how to create those paths? What would be the best way to manage those? We are talking about 10,000 - 30,000 images for starter..

So if someone have nice tips or maybe share some code, that would be awesome! :) Oh yea, I'm using CodeIgniter for this project if that helps?

Comment: We might be able to come up with better solutions if you can tell us what you're going to do with those images after they've been stored, like how is it supposed to be accessed, etc. It would be also useful to know if it's important to know who uploaded the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*KISS*:

```
date('Y')/date('md')/date('Hi')/md5($image).ext
```

It's pretty simple and I don't think you're going to exceed 32k files in any given minute.

---

If you don't need minutes and can work with a maximum of 8928 sub-directories you could just do:

```
date('Y')/date('mdH')/md5($image).ext
```

Comment: better than my solution as I didn't think about adding 32K images per day - just the initial batch of them :-)

Answer (score 1):

Turn the first 4 hex characters of the hash into the first level of directories, and the second 4 hex characters into the second level. Store the file in there with the full hash.

Comment: dude check that my url example?

Answer (score 0):

How about using an uuid?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a uid for the pics themselves, but isn't there a limit of 32,000 files per directory? This would almost be exceeded immediately so you'd still need some directory structure.

Couldn't you make a new folder with the date they're uploaded and keep that in one database column and the uid in another -> you're not going to exceed 32,000 days of images.